# Filter by sex and frequency and return conditional result

Tags: r, conditional-statements, shiny, dplyr

I have a Shiny app working with a dataframe.
Data-frame is like below:

```
Name  Gender  Frequency
John       M         45
Mary       F         32
```

My UI.R file has this widgets:

```
radioButtons("sex", "Sex:", c("Female", "Male"),
             selected = c("Female")),
             br(),
             textInput("searchText", "Search: ", "")
```

My server.R file has:

```
# reactive function
  getReactionDTResult <- reactive({
    return(list(
      text = input$searchText,
      sex = input$sex
    ))
  })
```

calculating function:

```
# Plot results of dataframe search
getDTResult <- function(df, reaction){
  maintable <-df[[1]]
  sex = reaction$sex
  name = reaction$text

  if (sex == "Female"){
    sex = "F"
  }
  else {sex = "M"}

    g1 <- maintable %>% filter(Name == name, Sex == sex)

  if(g1$Frequency == 0)

  { text = "Not found" }

  else if(g1$Frequency <= 3)

  {text = "There are less than 3 persons with this name"}

  else

  {text == "There are g1$Frequency men/women with this name"}

  return(text)
}
```

Output function

```
output$text <- renderText({print(getDTResult(localFrame, getReactionDTResult()))})
```

Now function should search the dataframe based on input name and sex and then return conditional result
If 0 text "there are no..."
If less than 3 "there are less than 3.."
Else "there are x person"

I cannot make my function work because it gives me error:

> Error in if (g1$Frequency == 0) { : argument is of length zero

Please help

Comment: You forgot a `"` in `{text == "There are g1$Frequency men/women with this name}`.

Comment: Pascal thx. It still doesn't print the result.

Comment: I guess you don't get this error anymore, right?

Comment: My guess is that your selections are initially `NULL` and since you haven't included those test cases it complains

Comment: Thx Pork Chop. How can it be corrected?

Comment: @Pascal No I am still getting the same error.

Comment: You are always going to get this error if the two choices don't intersect - just take this out of shiny and try to use your function when `Sex == "Female"` and `Name == "John"`.  You'll likely have to code in something to deal with this.  Probably you'll want to replace `g1$Frequency == 0` with something like `nrow(g1) == 0`.